# Subsection and section numbers

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have question because I can't find anywhere answer. Is it possible in latex to number sections like this:

```
14 First (here I now `\addtocounter{section}{21}`)
          But how can i do it with subsections?
14.4 First Subsection
14.5 Second Subsection
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: `\addtocounter{subsection}{3}`

Comment: Do you mean `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
 \setcounter{section}{13}
 \section{First}
 \setcounter{subsection}{3}
 \subsection{First}
 \subsection{Second}
\end{document}`?

Comment: Probably yes, but i have couple more question :

1) How can i set up counter of equation(or something other similar) from like 14.5 14.8 14.9
2) How can i heading of page which look like on the left name, in the middle title on the right number page (starting from 145, how set it ?) and under everything line.

Comment: since the question hasn't been answered yet, in this case, you should add in the questions about setting numbers; the answers are related.  you should be able to edit your own question.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

A call to `\section` steps the `section` counter *before* setting the actual title. So, using something like

```
\setcounter{section}{5}
\section{A section}% 6
```

will print the section as **6 A section**, rather than perhaps a more intuitive **5 A section**. The same goes for a subsection. So, if you want a specific sectional unit to have a number *X*, you can set it before that sectional unit to *X-1*:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{First}% 1

\addtocounter{section}{7}
\section{Second}% 8

\setcounter{section}{13}
\section{Third}% 14

\setcounter{subsection}{3}
\subsection{First subsection}% 14.4
\subsection{Second subsection}% 14.5

\end{document}
```

The only counter that doesn't work like this is the `page` counter, as it starts at `1` and is stepped after the page is constructed.